# Navigation Drawer Fragment Affecting Toolbar's Style and Positioning

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I'm desperately looking for help with an issue I'm having. So I've been following  [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lg4PVqRRO2Q) tutorial series, which are absolutely great, but in comparison to using a `Bottom Navigation` like he is in the video, I'm using a `Navigation Drawer' with fragments.

When I select `HomeFragment` within the `NavigationDrawer`, the layout loads but with everything pushed down below the `Toolbar`. Now, the Toolbar is fully functional as the hamburger and more options menu icon are indeed there, but are invisible to also being white, therefore it's more a Design issue.

[image]

Also, regarding the `Toolbar's` style, yes I've made it to be transparent on purpose so that the finished UI looks like the "Expected Output" image below.

**Expected Output** - This is what the identical layout looks like in `HomeActivity` in oppose to `HomeFragment`.

[image]

The below is my code for the `HomeActivity`, which nests the `FrameLayout` for the `Fragments`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.michaeldybek.plasticoceansapp.HomeActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar">
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@null"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have declared and initiated the `Toolbar` within the `HomeActivity` class like normal, and when the `HomeActivity` is displayed the `Toolbar` is indeed there, which makes me question whether I must declare it again within the `HomeFragment` class? If so, how would you go about doing that?

If any other code is required from other layouts or classes, ask away. Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a week of solid research, I have finally manage to come up with a solution which bypassed this issue!

I ended up removing the `Toolbar` and `FrameLayout`from `HomeActivity`, and instead created a new layout resource file and called it "`app_bar.xml`", which contained the following code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".core.MainActivity">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I then followed by including the `app_bar` in the `HomeActivity` layout using the `include` tag (`HomeActivity` also houses the `NavigationView` nested within a `DrawerLayout`).

I hope this helps whomever comes across this question. If you have any further queries, ask away!

Answer (score 0):

Either remove *android:background="@null"* or set  *android:background="@color/colorPrimary"* in Toolbar

Comment: I've tried it, and unfortunately it didn't work. As I said in the post, I'd like the `Toolbar` to be transparent, and setting the `background` to `colorPrimary` will set a colour to it.

Comment: then set your your background color to parent ConstraintLayout

Comment: Sorry that doesn't work either. You cannot set colour as a position, they are two different things.